# How to unsubscribe the httpclient request in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, httpclient, angular-promise

I've following http request

```
 getUsers(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let req = this._helper.getBaseUrl() + 'api/users/allUsers/' + this._helper.getUsertId();
            let sub = this._httpClient.get(req)
                .subscribe((response: any) => {
                    this.users = response.result;

                    this.users = this.users.map(user => {
                        return new Users(user);
                    });
                    this.onContactsChanged.next(this.users);
                    resolve(this.users);
                },(reject: any) => {
                        if (reject.status === 401 || reject.status === 403) {
                            location.href = '/login';
                            console.log("Unauthorized Request - In case of Auth Token Expired");
                        }
                    }
                );
        }
        );
    }
```

In reject response, because of unauthorized access, I want here unsubscribe requests before the goto login page.
Because I'm getting error in console of this request on the login page, and redirected again and again, and is repeated on every page. In .ts file, the onDestroy method is also defined.

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Unsubscribe from all subscriptions
        this._unsubscribeAll.next();
        this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
    }
```

How I stop this request in reject response.

Comment: Don't combine Observables and Promises. It's hard to maintain. Nevertheless, you have a variable called `sub` that contains the subscription to the observable returned from the HTTP GET method. Try calling `sub.unsubscribe()` where you need to cancel the request.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do this but this unsubscribe call first before getting error. I want unsub if request in reject.

Comment: That is why I said don't mix Observables and Promises. You cannot cancel a Promise whereas if you return the observable you could cancel it when you want.